# Async middleware in a express function with AWS Lambda (TypeError)

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, middleware, aws-serverless

I want to use an `async` function in my middleware that extracts the user in my AWS Lambda function.

Here is the code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) =>
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);

const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
const tapRoute = f => route => {
  route.use(f);
  return route;
};

const configureCors = route => {
  route.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    );
    next();
  });
};
const injectUser = route => {
  route.use(async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const IDP_REGEX = /.*\/.*,(.*)\/(.*):CognitoSignIn:(.*)/;
      const authProvider =
        req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.identity
          .cognitoAuthenticationProvider;
      const [, , , userId] = authProvider.match(IDP_REGEX);
      console.log(userId);
      console.log('Got user id');

      const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
      const listUsersResponse = await cognito
        .listUsers({
          UserPoolId: process.env.AUTH_LAMBDAUSERB2E6BC69_USERPOOLID,
          Filter: `sub = "${userId}"`,
          Limit: 1,
        })
        .promise();
      console.log('ListedUsers');
      const user = listUsersResponse.Users[0];
      req.user = user;
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      next(error);
    } finally {
      return route;
    }
  });
};

const applyMiddleware = (route, ...middleware) =>
  pipe(
    tapRoute(bodyParser.json()),
    tapRoute(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext()),
    configureCors,
    injectUser,
    ...middleware
  )(route);

module.exports = {
  applyMiddleware,
};
```

The code throws an error in this line:

```
route.use(async function(req, res, next) {
```

And here is the error:

```
module initialization error: TypeError
at injectUser (/var/task/middleware.js:25:9)
at fns.reduce (/var/task/middleware.js:8:52)
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at x (/var/task/middleware.js:8:35)
at applyMiddleware (/var/task/middleware.js:63:4)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/app.js:13:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Generally, I later use this middleware like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const applyMiddleware = require('./middleware').applyMiddleware;

const app = express();
applyMiddleware(app);

app.get( // ... rest of the code
```

But sometimes I also inject middleware on a per route basis.

What is going on? Why is this TypeError being thrown? Is there a way I can use the async middleware that injects the user in my pipe, so that I can reduce my boilerplate? If I comment out `injectUser` the middleware works...

**Edit:**

Using `app.use(async function // ...` works, but I'd like to have the async function in my `pipe` aka. in `applyMiddleware`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal git repo to reproduce the issue? It's a bit hard right now to understand the exception

Comment: @TarunLalwani It is actually the minimal example. I can't clutter it less, because all middleware is needed. But I made a gist (https://gist.github.com/janhesters/26a9b2105696f31206e23627b6c7b77d) where I tried to explain it differently. Let me know if this helps, or if you have further questions, because I'm super stuck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `configureCors` function. You don't return anything there, so the chain gets broken and `injectUser` gets a `undefined` `route` variable. It should be updated like below

```
const configureCors = route => {
  route.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    );
    next();

  });
  return route;
};
```